# React useState can't assign setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

```
let [mapPredictionData, setMapPredictionData] = useState({
        prediction_index    : 0,
        prediction_point    : null,
        prediction_point_distance : null
    })

.....some other code

setMapPredictionData({
        prediction_index: prev_index,
        prediction_point: props.missionLocationArray[prev_index],
        prediction_point_distance: get_distance_between_points(props.missionLocationArray[prev_index], currentPosition)
    })
```

Above is how I declare my state using React hooks useState and following how I set the same state. 
But every time I set the state it usually doesn't change and I get the error -

"Argument type {prediction_index: number, prediction_point_distance: number, prediction_point: *} is not assignable to parameter type ((prevState: {prediction_index: number, prediction_point_distance: null, prediction_point: null}) => {prediction_index: number, prediction_point_distance: null, prediction_point: null}) | {prediction_index: number, prediction_point_distance: null, prediction_point: null} "

I tried researching for the solution but failed. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: are you using typescript? Looks like React really doesn't like the default value of null for your ```prediction_point``` and ```prediction_point_distance```

Comment: @AdamJeliński No, simply javascript. But I have done with several other times when using useState and giving them an initial value as null. And it appears to work fine every time.

Comment: This is very weird, I have never seen this happen in JS. What is the ```props.missionLocationArray[prev_index]```? For some reason it got a type of ```*``` and this might be problematic for the interpreter

Comment: @AdamJeliński props.missioLocationArray is an Array, while prev_index is part of the for-loop index (prev_index = index --). Value of props.missionLocationArray[prev_index] is an object.

Comment: @AdamJeliński any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what this could be :( I have never encountered a type error in JS.